# Was it common to hide food to avoid it being confiscated during the early stages of the Holodomor?

Tags: historical-context, the-memory-keeper-of-kyiv, erin-litteken

In *The Memory-Keeper of Kyiv*, Katya and Pavlo hide food in various locations and kept notes on where they hid it to keep it from being confiscated by the Soviet activists pushing for collectivization. Was this actually a common practice? If so, how effective was it? Did the Soviet activists ever "catch on" to this?

Comment: wouldn't you? ..

Comment: @Andra Yeah, probably... I'm assuming that people actually did that and it's not just the novel. I'm just curious if it's known how frequently this happened, and if the Soviets ever figured out that people were doing that.

Comment: "Kulaks, wreckers, and *hoarders*" -- they certainly figured it out, and probably long before the Holodomor.

Comment: I expect the Soviets did not have enough guards present in the Ukraine to comprehensively search and find all the hiding places the Ukrainians used.

Comment: I have seen it depicted in other fictional works, but it would be good if someone could write a historical answer